# I'm getting this error --> TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, compiler-errors

I'm trying to learn object oriented programming by making a text based rpg which is shown below. The parts of it that are related to my question are:

```
    def equipArmor(self):
        for armor in self.armorsOwned:
            select = 1
            if self.armor == armor:
                print(str(select) + ". " + str(armor["Name"]) + " (Equipped)")
            else:
                print(str(select) + ". " + str(armor["Name"]))
            select += 1
        armor_choice = input("Type the name of the armor you would like to equip\n")
        for i in self.armorsOwned:
            if armor_choice == i["Name"]:
                if self.armor == i:
                    print("You already have that equipped")
                else:
                    self.armor = i["Name"]
                    print("You equipped the {}".format(i["Name"]))
                    self.maxhp += i["Effect"]
```

and:

```
class Shop:

    armors = {"BronzeArmor":{"Name": "Bronze armor",
                             "Cost": 30,
                             "Effect": 10},
              "SilverArmor":{"Name": "Silver armor",
                             "Cost": 75,
                             "Effect": 20}}
```

Here is the rest just so you can understand the context of my code:

```
import time
import sys

class Player:

    def __init__(self):
        self.level = 1
        self.exp = 0
        self.gold = 0
        self.maxhp = 20
        self.hp = self.maxhp
        self.attack = 1
        self.weapon = ""
        self.armor = ""
        self.weaponsOwned = {}
        self.armorsOwned = {}

    def checkHp(self):
        self.hp = max(0, min(self.hp, self.maxhp))

    def deadCheck(self):
        if self.hp == 0:
            print("You died!")
            sys.exit()

    def equipArmor(self):
        for armor in self.armorsOwned:
            select = 1
            if self.armor == armor:
                print(str(select) + ". " + str(armor["Name"]) + " (Equipped)")
            else:
                print(str(select) + ". " + str(armor["Name"]))
            select += 1
        armor_choice = input("Type the name of the armor you would like to equip\n")
        for i in self.armorsOwned:
            if armor_choice == i["Name"]:
                if self.armor == i:
                    print("You already have that equipped")
                else:
                    self.armor = i["Name"]
                    print("You equipped the {}".format(i["Name"]))
                    self.maxhp += i["Effect"]

class Enemy:

    def __init__(self, attack, maxhp, exp, gold):
        self.exp = exp
        self.gold = gold
        self.maxhp = maxhp
        self.hp = maxhp
        self.attack = attack

    def checkHp(self):
        self.hp = max(0, min(self.hp, self.maxhp))

    def enemyDeadCheck(self):
        if self.hp == 0:
            return True

class Shop:

    armors = {"BronzeArmor":{"Name": "Bronze armor",
                             "Cost": 30,
                             "Effect": 10},
              "SilverArmor":{"Name": "Silver armor",
                             "Cost": 75,
                             "Effect": 20}}

character = Player()
character.armorsOwned.update(Shop.armors["BronzeArmor"])
character.equipArmor()
```

What I'm trying to do is print out all of the armors I have, print "equipped" beside it if it's equipped, receive the name of the armor to equip from input, check if it is already equipped and then equip it if it isn't equipped. However, the error mentioned in the title is preventing me from doing that. Why is that so and what is a string indice?

Comment: An error message isn't just the `SomethingError: several words here` part. There's a stack trace, too, and it's full of useful information about where and how the problem occurred. Don't remove the stack trace!

Answer (score 1):

Loops over dictionaries (for example, `for i in self.armorsOwned`) return an iterable of the *keys*, not the entries. So `i` is being set to the key string, not the armor dictionary.

You want to turn all your loops over dictionaries to something like:

`for i in self.armorsOwned.values():`

Answer (score 1):

Dont have enough points to make comment hence posting as answer.
This error is generally thrown when you treat a list like a dictionary.

It'd be helpful if you could include the #line that shows the error so that I could pin-point but to me this looks fishy:

```
self.armorsOwned = {}
```

If it's just a dictionary of armor. In that case, this is how you would extract the armor-name:

```
        if self.armor == armor:
            print(str(select) + ". " + str(self.armorsOwned[armor]["Name"]) + " (Equipped)")
        else:
            print(str(select) + ". " + str(self.armorsOwned[armor]["Name"]))
```

You could also try printing the values of these variables to see what they contain before doing any string manipulation:

```
def equipArmor(self):
        print(self.armorsOwned)
        for armor in self.armorsOwned:
            print(armor)
            select = 1
```

Comment: i tried this but the error was still there. Is there something else I might be doing wrong?

Comment: attach the stack-trace(error log) with the question. That should help.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mohdi\Downloads\Python\Python OOP RPG.py", line 72, in <module>
    character.equipArmor()
  File "C:\Users\mohdi\Downloads\Python\Python OOP RPG.py", line 33, in equipArmor
    print(str(select) + ". " + str(armor["Name"]))
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: I believe armor or  self.armorsOwned is empty/not-initialized at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

`TypeError: string indices must be integers` is a very common error in Python, especially during development. It indicates that your variable is a string, but you are trying to use it as a dictionary.

example:

```
x = {'Name': 'Bronze Armor'}
print(x['Name']) #    Bronze Armor

x = 'Bronze Armor'
print(x['Name']) #    raises TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Look at error's stack trace, it will tell you in which line you made the mistake.